# NullPointerException by loading JSON Content with volley

Tags: java, android, json, fragment, android-volley

im trying to load content from a URL with Volley into a listview in a fragment, but every time i get a NullPointerException und i dont really know what im doing wrong. I hope you can help me and point out my mistakes:

```
public class Neuigkeiten extends Fragment
{
  // Neuigkeiten URL
public static final String neuigkeitenURL = //my URL
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = Neuigkeiten.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog progress;
private List< NeuigkeitenBean > neuigkeitenListe = new ArrayList< NeuigkeitenBean >();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container ,
        Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    View neuigkeitenView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listmainview ,
            container , false);
    progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    listView = (ListView) neuigkeitenView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this , neuigkeitenListe);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // hole die SharedPreferences
    final SharedPreferences sharedPf = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    // hole die Datenbank, die nachher zum Server geschickt werden muss
    String datenbank = sharedPf.getString("Datenbank" , "");

    //POST Parameter 
    JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        parameter.put("datenbank" , datenbank);
    }
    catch (JSONException je)
    {
        //wenn das hier auf die Fresse fliegt breche alles ab;
        je.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonAntwort = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST ,
            neuigkeitenURL , parameter , new Response.Listener< JSONObject >()
            {

                @Override
                public void onResponse( JSONObject response )
                {
                    Log.d(TAG , response.toString());
                    progress.hide();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            NeuigkeitenBean neuigkeitenBean = new NeuigkeitenBean();
                            neuigkeitenBean.setUeberschrift(response.getString("head"));
                            neuigkeitenBean.setText((response.getString("content")));
                            neuigkeitenBean.setBild(response.getString("image"));

                            // Bean zur Liste hinzufügen
                            neuigkeitenListe.add(neuigkeitenBean);

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }       
                }
                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } , new Response.ErrorListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse( VolleyError error )
                {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG , "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    progress.dismiss();

                }
            });
    NeuigkeitenHelper.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonAntwort);

    return neuigkeitenView;
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
   12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335): java.lang.NullPointerException
   12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):  at                com.sits.activitys.Neuigkeiten.onCreateView(Neuigkeiten.java:114)
   12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):  at       android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
   12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
   12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
   12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-04 19:22:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The variable jsonAntwort is empty, but im sure that the params are right....line 114 :

```
NeuigkeitenHelper.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonAntwort);
```

Comment: Attach your stack trace and show where the error is happening.

Comment: `NeuigkeitenHelper.getInstance()` is null.
You should check this variable. Can you explain what this variable is actually doing?

Answer (score -1):

Check once in your Manifest if NeuigkeitenHelper extends Application. then you should use that class in Application tag in Manifest.

Exapmle :

```
<application
    android:name="package.YourApplicationClass"  <--------
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="xyz"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: why? why should `NeuigkeitenHelper` extend Application? How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: NeuigkeitenHelper is not my start Class. I use it to instantiate some objects like the RequestQeue.

Comment: i have found my issue. the instance was null, but i have no idea why...i create a new instance in my Neuigkeiten class and it works!

Comment: Once post your source code of NeuigkeitenHelper. Then i'll confirm why should you use in manifest.